# the time() function (python)

Tags: python, sockets, time, irc

```
    if data.find('!google') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     if last_google + 5 > time.time():
        sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" + ' Wait a few seconds' + "\r\n")
     else:
           last_google = time.time()
           try:
                gs = GoogleSearch(args)
                gs.results_per_page = 1
                results = gs.get_results()
                for res in results:
                    sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + res.title.encode("utf8") + '\r\n')
                    sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + res.url.encode("utf8") + '\r\n')
                    print
           except SearchError, e:
                    sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " " + "Search failed: %s" % e + " " + '\r\n')
```

Ok I'm trying to make the script wait a few seconds before another user can "!google" to prevent users from flooding the channel or the bot.. Obviously this script doesnt work, I'm implementing the time function wrong or I'm missing something

Comment: Where does the `last_google` variable exist? Is it a local variable, a class variable, a global variable, or what? What do you see if you print out the current value of `last_google` before the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Is this all in a loop?

One issue is that you set last_google to time.time() at the beginning of your request.  If the request is slow, some of that time may already be gone by the time you get to the if statement again.

A typical 'waiting' block might look something like this:

```
while time.time() < last_google + 5:
    sleep(1) # You don't want to keep using the cpu, so let your process sleep
```

Comment: I think the sleep() function will stop the script completely, I tried the while loop but it doesnt do anything

Comment: If what you want to do is stop your script for a certain amount of time, time.sleep(x) is the way to do it.  If you're always trying to wait 5 seconds since last_google was set, put `sleep(last_google + 5 - time.time())` inside your if statement.  Like Greg Hewgill asked, the context in which this code is run is important, so you'll need to give us a bit more information for any more help.